# How to target firefox or any other browser in SCSS?

Tags: css, firefox, sass

The glyphicon is misaligned and is not behaving properly in Firefox whereas it looks perfect in Chrome and Safari. To solve this, I am trying to write a rule which would just apply if it is a Mozilla's browser.

Is there any way to detect a browser in SCSS by using directives like @if. Something like following:

```
@if $browser === mozilla {
    //apply this CSS
   .pull-right.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right {
    top: -13px;
    line-height: 0.5 !important;
}
```

Do we have any simple way to detect? I tried using the `@moz-document url-prefix()` which isn't working in SCSS.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623349/using-moz-document-url-prefix-to-target-firefox-in-scss) but there is no correct solution to the problem.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try JS console.log(navigator.userAgent);

Comment: I'm trying to do it only with Sass. I don't want to incorporate JavaScript here.  With JS, its quite straight forward, I am trying to find a way or to find out if it is possible with Sass. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only

Comment: first find the way how browsers you need has to be targeted (like @moz-document) and then create a mixin, so you can call it for example as `@include browser(firefox) { ruleset }`

Comment: Can you post an example snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get scss to compile when the prefix rule was used a mixin, but not otherwise:

```
@mixin firefox-only {
  @at-root {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
      & {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then

```
@include firefox-only {
  prop: val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to fix an issue I had with text-indent on Firefox being applied for double the width.

```
select {
 text-indent: calc(50% - 16px);

 @supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  text-indent: calc(25% - 8px);
 }
}
```